# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have three files

```
#!/bin/sh

# const variables
BUCKET_NAME=gs://rasa-models-staging
PROJECT_NAME=stage
KEY_FILE=./stage.json

# install dependencies
pip install google-cloud-storage
     
# Login to gscloud
gcloud auth activate-service-account --project=$PROJECT_NAME --key-file=$KEY_FILE

# Run gsutil command 
FILE_NAME=`gsutil ls -l $BUCKET_NAME | sort -k2 | tail -n2 | head -n1 | awk 'END {$1=$2=""; sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); print }'` 

# if file not found then set default file name
if [ -z "$FILE_NAME" ]; then
  FILE_NAME='/app/default_models/default.tar.gz'
fi

echo $FILE_NAME

# Then run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

DockerFile

```
FROM rasa/rasa:3.1.0-full

ADD . /app

RUN whoami

USER root

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

RUN [ "chmod", "+x", "/app/entrypoint.sh" ] 

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]

USER rasa

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c" "run --enable-API --auth-token secret --model $FILE_NAME"]
```

**Problem:** I have tried many ways to restructure the docker file, installing `google-cloud-storage` and adding `--user` nothing worked. Can anyone please help me?
I get this error when I do `docker compose up`

**Error :**
[image]

**Error Message :**
`Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.56.4-py3.10-nspkg.pth'`

Comment: It would be much easier to read the error message in plain text, rather than seeing the PNG-format rendering of it.  Can you [edit] the question to fix this?

Comment: @DavidMaze editing done

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to globally `pip install` something in the entrypoint script, every time the container starts up.  The `ENTRYPOINT` (and its `CMD` argument) always run with the final `USER` in the Dockerfile (or a `docker run -u` or Compose `user:` override) even if that appears after the `ENTRYPOINT` declaration.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ...
USER rasa # <-- the ENTRYPOINT runs as this user
CMD ...   # <-- passed as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT
```

For this setup, you probably want to only install the package once, in the image, rather than every time you start the container.  You can extract this into the Dockerfile

```bash
USER root
COPY entrypoint.sh ./  # preserves its executable bit from the host
RUN pip install google-cloud-storage
...

USER rasa
```

The `gcloud auth` command depends on runtime environment variables that can't be put into the image, so it must run in the entrypoint script.  It's possible that you'll hit a similar permission problem here, depending on what exactly that command does (the `HOME` environment variable might not be set and this might cause problems); you'd have to debug that separately.

Comment: Now it is saying that gcloud is not found. Is there any way that if I install anything through the root user, it is also available in entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Anything you install in the Dockerfile should be accessible to the main container process, yes.